# R: Combine entries of contingency table in character vector

Tags: r, contingency

I have a data.frame and made a contingency table of one column

```
> table(data$COLX)

AAAAAAA BBBBBBB CCCCCCC DDDDDDD EEEEEEE FFFFFFF
   2254    3399    3163    2040    7710    2368
```

With `unique(data$COLX)` I get a character vector with `AAAAAAA BBBBBBB ...`

How can I create a character vector that also contains the amount of occurences?

What I want to achieve is a character vector that looks like this

```
AAAAAAA (2254x)    BBBBBBB (3399x)    ...
```

Comment: Not much clear. Are you looking for `x<-table(data$COLX);paste0(names(x)," (",x,"x)")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:

```
x <- table(data$COLX)
paste(names(x), paste0("(", x, ")") )
```

**Example**

```
f <- gl(4, 4, labels = letters[1:4])
x <- table(f)
paste(names(x), paste0("(", x, ")") )
# [1] "a (4)" "b (4)" "c (4)" "d (4)"
```

Comment: sorry nicola, I did not see your comment so far

Answer (score -1):

I hope this is what you meant:

`tabl  <- structure(c(2254L, 3399L, 3163L, 2040L, 7710L, 2368L), .Dim = 6L, .Dimnames = structure(list(AAAAAAA", "BBBBBBB", "CCCCCCC", "DDDDDDD", "EEEEEEE", "FFFFFFF")), .Names = ""), class = "table")
data.frame(tabl)`

`Var1 Freq
1 AAAAAAA 2254
2 BBBBBBB 3399
3 CCCCCCC 3163
4 DDDDDDD 2040
5 EEEEEEE 7710
6 FFFFFFF 2368`